# Не будь равнодушен или не будь равнодушным?

Tags: грамотная-речь, семантика

Доброй всем ночи.

Как вы думаете, какой из предложенных вариантов написания является правильным? Допустимы ли оба варианта написания?

(1) не будь равнодушен

(2) не будь равнодушным

Comment: @Stanlie_Trout, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Краткие и полные формы прилагательных различаются по смыслу и стилю.

Полные прилагательные обозначают постоянный признак (он равнодушный), а краткие прилагательные обозначают признак, отнесенный к определенному времени, а также признак, обусловленный разными обстоятельствами (он сейчас равнодушен ко всему).

Краткие прилагательные соответствуют книжному стилю, а полные чаще используются в нейтральной и разговорной речи.

РЕШЕНИЕ

(1)  Не будь равнодушен к людям. Книжная речь, возможно указание на объект

(2) Не будь равнодушным, не проходи мимо тех, кому можешь помочь. Нейтральная речь.

ПРИМЕРЫ

"Будь честен, будь добр, не будь равнодушен". "Спасайся их молитвами и их любовью ― но чти, трудись в почитании, не будь равнодушен и забывчив в дни их памяти и небесного торжества"!

"Я сказала ей, что никакая это не доблесть, что во вмешательстве состоит половина человеческого общения, а оно, как известно, ― радость, и ничего тут не поделаешь, вмешиваться ― значит любить и не быть равнодушным".

Answer (score 2):

Мне оба варианта нравятся. Есть стилистическое различие: краткая форма придаёт возвышенный, "пафосный" оттенок, полная более нейтральна.